# JSON.stringify date convert into JSON.parse when return empty value

Tags: javascript, json, angular, stringify

I have a object convert into json string using JSON.stringify() and then I need same object with using of JSON.parse(), but I get array values are empty, how to I get original data, please help to solve this issue,
in below codes is stringify data

```
{
"agefrom":18,
"ageto":60,
"heightfrom":"1",
"heightto":"28",
"steps":["Never","One"],
"number":["One","two "],
"education":["B.E","B.E / B.Tech"]
}
```

below data after convert into JSON.parse

```
 {
        "agefrom":18,
        "ageto":60,
        "heightfrom":"1",
        "heightto":"28",
        "steps":"",
        "number":"",
        "education":""
   }
```

Comment: If your first object is your actual object (`obj`) doing `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));` gives back the same object, with the array values - no data is lost from stingifying and then parsing it

Comment: console.log return correct value, but here I assign that value like let val = JSON.parse(string_data); console.log(val); empty data like second object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank2567/agyuch7e/2/)
try this fiddle. it works fine for me.

```
 a = {
  "agefrom": 18,
  "ageto": 60,
  "heightfrom": "1",
  "heightto": "28",
  "steps": ["Never", "One"],
  "number": ["One", "two "],
  "education": ["B.E", "B.E / B.Tech"]
}
a = JSON.stringify(a)
document.write(a);
b = JSON.parse(a);
document.write(JSON.stringify(b))
```

Comment: did you get result?